# Why I cannot use progress bar within sidebar when using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I use progress bar, next contents appears in progress bar.
I want next contents on the bottom of progress bar with 50px margin.
How can I fix this?

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/VwmqV/

**HTML**

You are logged in

```
    <div class="progress progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width: 53%"></div>
    This message should be on the bottom of progress bar
</div>
```

**CSS**

It's way too long so please take a look at JS fiddle demo

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text is part of the first `<div>` which is the container of the progress bar. Place it *after* the `<div>`. So you should have this instead:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 53%"></div>
</div>
This message should be on the bottom of progress bar
```

Comment: No problem. That's why it's always a good thing to have another person to look at your code :)